# POST request using curl to Actix Server failing with "400 Bad Request"

Tags: curl, rust, amazon-ses, actix-web

I'm trying to build an actix server using `actix-web = "3.3.2"` to send a POST request to AWS SES which will send an email to the address provided in the body to the route. I've created a route, called `signup` which returns a 400 response with the following `curl` request:

`curl -i POST -d "name=test_name&email=testemail@test.com" 127.0.0.1:8000/signup -v`.

I've also tried sending a `json` object for the `-d` arg with:

`curl -i POST -d '{"name": "test_name", "email": "testemail@test.com"}' 127.0.0.1:8000/signup -v`

Both respond with:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x5c7286c42fb0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x5c7286c42fb0)
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#1)
> POST /signup HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 42
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 42 out of 42 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< content-length: 0
content-length: 0

< 
* Connection #1 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

In my `main.rs` file, I have the following which creates the actix server running on port 8000.

```
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), StdErr> {
    env_logger::init();
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        actix_web::App::new()
            .wrap(Logger::default())
            .service(signup)
    })
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8000))?
        .run()
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

My service, `signup` is located at `src/signup` which contain a `mod.rs` that exposes `pub mod routes` from my `routes.rs` file where I've written the following:

```
#[post("/signup")]
pub async fn signup(body: actix_web::web::Json<SignupBody>) -> impl Responder {
    let name = &body.name;
    let email = &body.email;

    let message = send_message(name.to_string(), email.to_string()) 
        .await;

    match message {
        Ok(()) => {
            web::Json(
                SignupResp::Success(Success{ message: "Email Sent Successfully".into() })
            )
        }

        Err(e) => {
            web::Json(
                SignupResp::ErrorResp(ErrorResp{ message: format!("{}", e) })  

            )
        }
    }
}

async fn send_message(name: String, email: String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let ses_client = SesClient::new(rusoto_core::Region::UsEast1);
    let from = "Test <test@test.com>";
    let to = format!("{}, <{}>", name, email); 
    let subject = "Signup";
    let body = "<h1>User Signup</h1>".to_string();

    send_email_ses(&ses_client, from, &to, subject, body).await
}

async fn send_email_ses(
    ses_client: &SesClient,
    from: &str,
    to: &str,
    subject: &str,
    body: String,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let email = Message::builder()
        .from(from.parse()?)
        .to(to.parse()?)
        .subject(subject)
        .body(body.to_string())?;

    let raw_email = email.formatted();

    let ses_request = SendRawEmailRequest {
        raw_message: RawMessage {
            data: base64::encode(raw_email).into(),
        },
        ..Default::default()
    };

    ses_client.send_raw_email(ses_request).await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

I'm new to actix and wondering if someone could verify whether or not my `curl` request is malformed, or if I've messed something up in my actix server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your request is being rejected because it doesn't specify the content type.

In order to do so, you have to add the `Content-Type` header. In cURL you do it like this:

`-H "Content-Type: application/json"`